# bash/python stop reading from fifo

Tags: bash, fifo

I'm trying to get a short python script to read from a fifo under bash/linux and then stop when a certain word is received. i've done the following

in main.py

```
import "sys"
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
    sys.stdout.write(line + " read\n")
    if line=="STOP":
        break
sys.stdout.write("finished\n")
```

And i'm running the script like this:

```
mkfifo myfifo 
tail -f myfifo | python main.py
```

In another shell window I enter:

```
echo "foobar" > myfifo # "myfifo read" echoed in the other window
echo "STOP" > myfifo # "finished" echoed in other window
```

However, the process in the other window doesn't stop but remains open until i echo something else to myfifo.

Does anybody know what's going on here and how to get the python process to quit?

--- edit ---

I've just rewritten main.py as a bash script and it has the same problem. This seems to be a behaviour of tail -f which i am unfamiliar with

--- another edit ---

If i search for the python process after having entered "STOP" i can't find it anymore. This means that the python process is finishing. The problem seems to be some interaction between tail -f and bash.

--- possibly final edit ---

Okay, i think i've worked out what's going on and it has nothing to do with python.

when you echo something to a named pipe, an `EOF` is added to the end. `tail -f` transmutes an `EOF` into an `EOL`. That means that if i don't use `tail -f` but instead use `cat` to pipe the contents of the named pipe to `stdin` of the python script, python will lose a connection to `stdin` after having read the `EOF` at the end of the first line. From then on, trying to read from `stdin` will result in an `EOF`. For this reason, the python script will display an infinite list of `read\n`. If, when using `tail -f` the python script quits, `tail -f` doesn't know about this until i add something else to the named pipe.

Answer (score 1):

`tail -f` keeps the pipe open indefinitely, so you should call `sys.stdin.close()` once you're done reading from it:

```
import sys

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
    sys.stdout.write(line + " read\n")
    if line == "STOP":
        break

sys.stdin.close()
sys.stdout.write("finished\n")
```

Off-topic, but I also changed your `import "sys"` to `import sys`.

Answer (score 0):

It's the tail.

```
./tst.py<myfifo &
```

then send anything you want into the pipe. The code is working (though I had to strip the quotes off sys for my version of python.) Your problem is that tail is still running in -f follow mode.

Comment: The trouble with this is that if i then echo something to myfifo, the python script will output an infinite list of " read\n". I have no idea why.

Comment: Edit your original post to show exactly how you set up and execute. Don't use tail or pipes aside from the fifo. Keep is as simple and minimal as possible.